# Generating barcode image in salesforce apex email with a generated sting in flows

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, salesforce-flow

I have a string that is generated in the flows, for example, the generated sting is '998798474610237811'. I would like to transfer it to a barcode with ext39b method and send it through a email with other variables. The current way I am using is sending apex better email in flows.

I have done some research and found that most of them need to save the image on salesforce, however, i dont want to save the image on salesforce. Is there any way to do that?

I have checked a way called AMPscript, but I have no idea how can it combine with sending apex better email in flows. PLease help. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to set up a new formula with Data Type Text, let call it 'Barcode'. In the text, you need to paste the follwing code.

```
"http://bwipjs-api.metafloor.com/?bcid=code39ext&text="+{!your_variable}
```

After that, creat a text template with view as Plain Text
Then paste the following code in it

```
<img src="{!Barcode}" width="200" height="50">
```

Then you can try to send the email with flows. The barcode will appear on the emails.